# How to solve the Lienard equation $v'' = av -bvv'$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For a Physics project that I'm doing in school, I have the following differential equation:

$$v'' = av -bvv'$$

where $v$ is the velocity, $v'$ is the rate of change of velocity with respect to time, and $v''$ is the second derivative of the velocity with respect to time. 
$a$ and $b$ are both positive constants.
I also know the initial velocity and the initial rate of change of velocity when $t=0$.

It's really important that I solve it, and I'm not able to find the solution anywhere.

This is really urgent, and I hope one of you guys can solve this equation soon.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? I believe the intention of whoever assigned this problem to you was for you to do it yourself, not find a solution online. Please include any work you have tried and what you are having difficulty with in your question. Thanks!

Comment: The equation has not been given to me. I created it for a physics paper that I am writing, but I'm stuck and am not able to solve it. Any help from you would be much appreciated

Comment: I see. Have you taken a class in Differential Equations or is the first time you're seeing them?

Comment: No, I have not taken any classes on it. But I have studied basic first order differential equations

Comment: Because of the $v v_{}^\prime$ term, this is not a linear differential equation.

Comment: I know that, this is a Lienard equation. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: My apologies, I thought you had misspelled linear.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard_equation

Comment: For a school project it seems appropriate to *linearize* the equation around the given initial point $(v_0,v_0')$. You then obtain a second-order linear ordinary differential equation with constant coefficients, which has a closed-form solution in terms of elementary functions.

Answer (score 1):

Let $w(v) = v'(t)$. Then the equation should become $ww' = av-bwv$ (show this). Then you should be able to take it from here.

Comment: Thank you, But I'm not sure how to take it further as there are now 3 variables in the equation. Sorry if I'm making an obvious mistake, I am new to this

Comment: No no, there are just two variables. Maybe it's safer to write the equation in the form $w \frac{dw}{dv} = - b v w + a v$. Here, $v$ is the new independent variable and $w$ is the new dependent variable.

Comment: The next step would be to define another new independent variable $z := -\frac{1}{2}b v^2$, $\frac{d}{dv} = - b v \frac{d}{dz}$. This will give you a separable first-order ODE for the function $w(z)$.

Comment: thank you, this helps. However, I still do not know how to solve an Abel equation. If you could solve it for me and show me your method, that would be great. If not, I'll try working with this.

Comment: Sorry, I had edited my comment. The Abel equation of the second kind is difficult to solve of course, but in your case, it will be *separable*. So you can use separation of variables to solve it.

Comment: Actually, the equation written down by AlexanderJ93 is already separable … I did one step too much.

Comment: I have been trying to solve this again using the information that you guys have provided and have had no luck. Could you please solve it for me @Christoph ? Thanks

Comment: Write $w \frac{dw}{dv} = - b v w + a v = v(a-bw)$ as $\frac{w}{a-bw} dw = v dv$, then integrate.

Comment: Thank you.. appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me remark that it seems impossible to obtain a closed-form solution in terms of elementary functions to this ordinary differential equation (ODE) in the general case.

Writing $v' = w(v)$ with a new function $w$, $v'' = w \frac{dw}{dv}$, we obtain the first-order separable ODE
\begin{equation}
w \frac{dw}{dv} = a v - b v w = v (a - b w).
\end{equation}
Assuming that $w \not \equiv \frac{a}{b}$ and using separation of variables we obtain
\begin{equation}
\frac{w}{a-bw} \, \mathrm{d}w = v \, \mathrm{d}v \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \ln\left|\frac{b}{a}w-1\right| + \frac{b}{a} w - 1 = - \frac{b^2}{2 a} v^2 + C_1, \quad C_1 \in \mathbb{R}.
\end{equation}
Therefore, the function $w(v)$ may be obtained in terms of the Lambert W function, which cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Finally, the solution of the separable ODE $\frac{dv}{dt} = w(v)$ yields an implicit representation
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{1}{w(v)} \, \mathrm{d}v = t
\end{equation}
for $v$, with the function $w(v)$ from above, where the indefinite integral contains the second constant of integration. The values of the two constants of integration will be determined from the given initial values $v(0), v'(0)$.

Edit: The solution of the initial-value problem $v'' = a v - b v v'$, $v(0) = v_0$, $v'(0) = \frac{a}{b}$, is given by the linear function $v(t) = \frac{a}{b} t + v_0$. This is the special case of a constant $w \equiv \frac{a}{b}$, for which we don't need to do the separation of variables.